# How to conditionally validate a nested bean using hibernate bean validation

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

I have a form call Cart. 
This form contains a nested bean Address. The Cart form has property useShipppingAddressAsBillingAddress. 
If this property is set, Address bean should not be validated but ignored. It should be validated if otherwise.

Tried various options like Composing. However, I do not want to put this Custom annotation in every form field. I would like the @Valid annotation put on the Address bean be made conditional.

Right now form attribute looks like this:

```
@Valid
private Address shippingAddress;
```

Any help here would be appreciated.